# Apple G5 Heatsink on AM3 mobo?

Tags: cooling, heatsink, powerpc, am3

I've been looking to replace my PhenomII 965be's stock heatsink, and my old G5's massive heatsink has drawn my attention.

Do you think it would somehow be possible or am I going too far?

my mobo: [GA-MA790FXT-UD5P](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3005#ov)

and there are 2x HD5870s connected to it.

Comment: Apple does not use AMD .  So you won't be able to properly mount and secure the G5's Heatsink.  Since the G5 used neither Intel or AMD the likelyhood of an IBM heatsink fitting is less then 0%.

Comment: That's exactly my question though, I know it's highly improbable but I'm looking for a more certain answer.

Comment: It is 100% improbable.  In other words not possible.